# custom css inside table being overide bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

div inside table not affected

css

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr > td .title-intbl ul{
    list-style: outside none none !important;
    margin:0;
}
```

table code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<td><div class="title-intbl"><ul><li>title</li>
<li> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Edit</a></li>
</ul></div>
</td></table>
```

image:

[image: list image]

Comment: You don't have a tbody, therefore the selector doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `<tbody>` in your HTML, so the CSS selector finds no elements.